# How to capture optional GET parameters django (something wrong with queryparam page?)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, query-string

Say someone wants to `GET` an entity called a `Volume`, which is a model in django. I have exposed an endpoint:

```
urlpatterns = [ ... 
    path('vol', views.volume_view, name='volume query'),
    path('vol/<str:volume>', views.volume_view, name='volume specific query'),
    ... ]
```

and the view `volume_view` has a signature like (it's inside of a `GenericViewSet`):

```
def volume_view(self, request, volume="", format=None):
    ...
```

All is good when the user makes a request like:

```
requests.get("http:/.../my_app/vol")
```

or, if the user makes a request like:

```
requests.get("http:/.../my_app/vol/some_prefix_here")
```

which returns to the user *all* of the volumes that I currently have stored, and a subset, respectively. However, I wanted to allow for some smart, optional, options, like:

- `page`: do you want to paginate the responses?
- `from` and `to`: timestamps to give a range query.
- `prefix`: search for any volume matching this prefix.

So I thought, put them inside the `request.GET` header dictionary. Once I put in for example:

```
requests.get("http:/.../my_app/vol", params={"page":False})
```

The urlpatterns could not find it! Which makes sense, since in GET's, the params are appended to your url as a querystring:

When I run `python manage.py runserver` on this, I get this with no querystring:

```
[02/May/2018 22:23:13] "GET /my_app/vol HTTP/1.1" 200 123
```

And this when I do run it with a querystring:

```
Not Found: /my_app/vol
[02/May/2018 22:42:43] "GET /my_app/vol?page=False HTTP/1.1" 404 26
```

And so I ask, what is the proper way of handling this situation? Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

Selcuk reassured me that I wrote something wrong so I dug into the manage.py shell and ran some requests manually on a `/abcd` url, and look what happened:

```
>>> requests.get('http://lx-chmmutil02:8000/.../abcd/')
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://lx-chmmutil02:8000/.../abcd/', params={"foo":"bar"})
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://lx-chmmutil02:8000/.../abcd/', params={"page":"False"})
<Response [404]>
>>> requests.get('http://lx-chmmutil02:8000/.../abcd/', params={"boo":"True"})
<Response [200]>
>>> requests.get('http://lx-chmmutil02:8000/../abcd/', params={"boo":"False"})
<Response [200]>
```

Any requests going to /abcd/ with parameters containing the word page dies immediately. Somewhere in a middleware or django itself, it is intercepting that key word and exploding.

*Is there something going on with the key word `page` or am I going insane?*

If I change my keyword to not include "page", it works.

Some things I'm using:

- DRF's `ModelViewSet` for the view, and `volume_view = SomeViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})`.
- DRF's `Serializer` class.
- DRF's `LimitOffsetPagination` class.

Comment: I don't believe you would ever get a `404` because of URL routing in the latter case. I suspect you have changed something in between or you are raising the 404 yourself within your view. It could help if you post your whole `volume_view` method.

Comment: Have you tried using `request.query_params.get('page')` inside your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the issue was actually in my own stupidity:

I had a *custom paginator/permissions/preprocessing mixin base class* that applied to a subset of my views. This paginator base class uses PageNumberPagination pretty much. I copy pasted the boilerplate class definition to a lot of views and before I knew it the page parameter was taken by that paginator before it gets caught in my actual view.

**tl;dr: When you mix DRF's middleware into your views, know exactly what you're mixing in and what kind of queryparams they require to function.**